# Can i mix Time and IF functions in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to make a formula where :
If the time now is between 6:00 am and 8:00 am then type the word "early"
is it possible rephrase this in excel to achieve the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use any one of the following, assuming Cell A1 has a Time Value

```
=IF(AND(A1>=TIME(6,0,0),A1<=TIME(8,0,0)),"Early","")
```

or

```
=IF(AND(A1>="06:00:00",A1<="08:00:00"),"Early","")
```

Comment: You may consider converting Mayukh's formula into a `built-in-function`.  Just type the function name and pass the parameter in it.  Like this.  `=isItEarly(A1)`.